# How to add Free Shipping just for a City?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created a rule for shopping cart that gives free shipping for a region/state. Problem is that i need free shipping just for a city.

Here i have the next atributes Shipping Postcode, Shipping Region, Shipping State/Province, Shipping Country.

How can i add Shipping City ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer :

Rewrite /app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php file with some local module and change these lines

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
{
$attributes = array(
    'base_subtotal' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Subtotal'),
    'total_qty' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Items Quantity'),
    'weight' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Weight'),
    'payment_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Payment Method'),
    'shipping_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Method'),
    'postcode' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
    'region' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Region'),
    'region_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping State/Province'),
    'country_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Country'),
);
$this->setAttributeOption($attributes);
return $this;
}
```

with

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
{
    $attributes = array(
        'base_subtotal' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Subtotal'),
        'total_qty' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Items Quantity'),
        'weight' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Weight'),
        'payment_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Payment Method'),
        'shipping_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Method'),
        'postcode' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
        'region' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Region'),
        'region_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping State/Province'),
        'country_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Country'),
        'city' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping City'),
    );
    $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);
    return $this;
}
```